# sql query FULL OUTER, CASE WHEN in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I want to pull all the columns from table CLIENT and only the phone number from table CLIPHONE. For the phone number, some clients have multiple phone numbers listed in CLIPHONE but, I only want one phone number. So if a client has their "cell" or "mobile" listed in the description then I want the number with the smallest sequence value. If cell or mobile is not listed then I want the sequence set to 1

Example: in CLIPHONE

Joey A - clientid = 25, sourceloc = 1, phone = 1234567890, description = home, sequence = 1

Joey A - clientid = 25, sourceloc = 1, phone = 0987654321, description = cell, sequence = 2

Joey A - clientid = 25, sourceloc = 1, phone = 1111111111, description = mobile, sequence = 3

Then when I run the query I want the phone number 0987654321 to show up with the columns from CLIENT because it contains the word 'cell' in it and has a lower sequence than sequence 3 with 'mobile' in it. If phone with sequence #2 had the word office in the description then I would want sequence 3 to be shown in the query result because that it now the lowest with the word 'cell' or 'mobile' in it

If both sequence 2 and 3 were changed to 'other' then I would want the sequence 1 to show up because no other sequence has 'cell' or 'mobile'.

With my query I am getting this error: 
Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 cp.phone, c.*
FROM CLIENT C
FULL OUTER JOIN CLIPHONE CP
ON c.clientid = cp.clientid AND c.sourceloc = cp.sourceloc
WHERE cp.sequence = CASE WHEN (description LIKE '%mobile%' OR description LIKE '%cell%') THEN min(sequence) ELSE 1 END 
ORDER BY sourceloc, clientid
```

Here are my tables:

[CLIPHONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8PeB.png)

[CLIENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISGzH.png)

Comment: Please provide the schemas of the tables involved. thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Joey -- all your responses must be in the form of a question.  What is happening?  What would you like to happen?

Comment: @Malvolio -- I have a requirement where I want to pull all the columns from table CLIENT and only the phone number from table CLIPHONE. For the phone number, some clients have multiple phone numbers listed in CLIPHONE but, I only want one phone number. So if a client has their "cell" or "mobile" listed in the description then I want the number with the smallest sequence value. If cell or mobile is not listed then I want the sequence set to 1.

Comment: @Joey -- put the in the question!  Also, put the observed results in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
with phones as (
    select *,
        row_number over (
            partition by cp.clientid
            order by
                case when cp.description in ('cell', 'mobile') then 1 else 2 end,
                cp.sequence
        ) as rnk
    from CLIENT c inner join CLIPHONE cp
        on cp.clientid = c.clientid and cp.sourceloc = c.sourceloc
)
select * from phones where rnk = 1;
```

I doubt that you really needed a full outer join. The query should probably still work even if you add it back.